# Delete all instances of acad.lsp on C:\ except for

Tags: exception, batch-file

I'm using the following code to delete all instances of Acad.lsp found on my C:\ drive but I want to make one exception, which is C:\Autocad 2010\Support.

How can I achieve this?

```
del "C:\ICT\acad.lsp" /q /a /s
```

Answer (score 1):

From a command line you could use the batch file `for` command (I'm assuming that you're using a Windows command prompt or similar here). This is a powerful command that will let you loop through a set of "things" - with the right options, these "things" may be files.

The following command, when run in the `C:\ICT` directory, should do what you want:

```
for /F "usebackq" %a in (`dir /s /b acad.lsp ^| find /v "C:\Autocad 2010\Support"`) do @echo %a
```

Note that I'm using `@echo` here so that you can test that the results are as you expect before you change the `@echo` to `del`.

If you wanted to put this into a batch file, you should change `%a` to `%%a`.

A little explanation on what's happening:

`for /F "usebackq" %a in (...)` runs the command that is between the back-quotes, and runs the command following the `do` on each item that results. The command in my example above does a recursive `dir` for the file `acad.lsp`, and puts that through the `find` command to remove the one you want to keep. The remaining files are the ones that you will want to delete.